# Trying to figure out Windows 10 login delay; xperf shows explorer.exe hanging up on "Windows.Devices.Lights.dll"

Tags: windows-10, freeze, windows-10-v20h2

Situation:

- I boot up my laptop, log in to Windows, and everything loads up quickly as it should.
- After the system has been up for "a while", a second user logs in with fast user switching.
- For the second user, the system "hangs" at a mostly blank desktop for five minutes before things start working.  While the desktop is "hung", the taskbar is loaded with the start button and search bar but no program icons, the desktop is unresponsive, and the Start button/menu is unresponsive.

The hang is not user-specific.  I have five users on the laptop and any one of them can experience the login delay.  Even my own account which normally works fine will have the issue if I am not the first one to log in and try to log in after the system has been up for "a while".

I'm not sure how long "a while" is.  If I try to reproduce this issue by rebooting and then logging in with two users back-to-back, both logins work fine.  (That makes troubleshooting this by like disabling startup items & services and rebooting to check difficult.)

I was initially experiencing this with Windows 10, version 1909, and it has persisted after an upgrade to 20H2.  I actually have this issue on two different laptops, one Dell Precision M6700 and one Dell Precision 7510.  There isn't a whole lot of software overlap between the two, the 7510 doesn't have much on it besides Office / Acrobat / and a couple of Steam games.  They do have a similar hardware and driver setup.

While the second user is hung, if I switch back to the first user (where things are working fine) and do "Analyze wait chain" on the second (hung) user's explorer.exe instance, it shows that it is waiting for sihost.exe.

...Anyway, I've been "dealing with it" for a while but yesterday I took to xperf to try to figure out what is causing the delay.

I ran three different traces and they all came out strikingly similar.  Sure enough, the "UI delay" view shows a "COM Modal Loop" delay in explorer.exe for the duration of the hang.

[image: Performance Analyzer showing COM Modal Loop hang (green)]
*Performance Analyzer showing COM Modal Loop delay (green) for the duration of the hang at login*

I thought it odd that the hang/delay seems to be exactly 5 minutes long.  Well, turns out that it is not quite exactly 5 minutes long.  The traces are showing that it consistently hangs for 308 seconds (5 minutes + 8 seconds).

Anyway, I went to the "thread lifetimes" view and I can see that this lines up perfectly with a thread in explorer.exe that has a thread start module of "Windows.Devices.Lights.dll".  A number of other threads don't start running to do their business until this one terminates.

[image]
*COM Modal Loop delay (green at top) and Windows.Devices.Lights.dll thread in explorer.exe (red at bottom) occur at the same time and for the same duration*

...Anyway, here I have sort of reached the end of my rope.  I'm not super familiar with xperf.  Is there any way to dig in further to see what Explorer is trying to do here?  What is "Windows.Devices.Lights.dll" even for?  It has a description that just says "Windows Runtime Lights DLL".  I imagine that there is something that I can just turn off that will cause this behavior to stop.  I am tempted to just remove/rename this DLL file and see if that makes the problem go away.

Any insights appreciated...

[Edit]
Stumbled across this thread after posting, apparently it is related to the USB Microsoft Pro IntelliMouse, which I *do* have connected to both systems.  (No solution offered...)

[Microsoft Answers post](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-performance/windows-10-taskbar-explorer-hangs-with-second-user/5be3b1cc-19be-4ad2-88d9-4a07446b049e)

Comment: Since I noticed a common theme, Dell hardware, what Dell software do you have installed? [Windows.Devices.Lights.dll](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.lights?view=winrt-19041) only works with HID LampArrays.  **LampArray devices have
one or more Lamps (i.e. lights/LEDs/bulbs, etc…) that can be directly manipulated; setting state (on/off), brightness and color
(RGB).** - So what devices on your hardware match that description?

Comment: I have practically no Dell software installed, I like to keep the system clean of OEM stuff whenever I can.  Since making the post, I have determined that the issue is caused by the Microsoft Pro IntelliMouse which I also have connected to both laptops.  It has an adjustable color tail light.  The issue occurs with the Microsoft "Keyboard and Mouse Center" software installed... and also with it not installed.  However the issue does not occur if I unplug the mouse before the second user logs in.

Comment: You should verify you have the current version of the software in question, the problem you describe, sounds like something Microsoft would quickly discover and solve (but only after a software release).

Comment: I did try it with the latest version of the software from Microsoft.  It also occurs without the software installed.  I've confirmed it on a fresh Windows install now.  Got a Windows bug here, unnoticed most likely because not that many people use systems with fast user switching.

Comment: Sounds like since the LampArray is connected to the USB Root Hub, and there is potentially a bug with the discovery of the device, or perhaps the overall functionality of the device the only solution is to disabled the USB device or use an entirely different USB mouse.  The software now that I think about it would only allow you to program the buttons on the mouse.  It wouldn't stop the LampArray from being automatically discovered and being treated as an HID compliant device.

Comment: Bruce Dawson mentioned this question on Twitter; there's more info there for anyone running into this in future. https://twitter.com/BruceDawson0xB/status/1392178341826813953

Comment: I got this problem in December 2020 [https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/windows-10s-task-bar-is-not-responing-after-sign/dcf4448b-98e5-4cb3-adc9-6759c2135263]

Comment: @Aaron It seems fixed in Windows 11.

Comment: Good to hear...  I'm planning to wait a few months before upgrading to Windows 11, so it will be a while before I have a chance to check, but I will post back here with the results when the time comes.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was caused by the Microsoft Pro IntelliMouse.

In Device Manager (View → Devices by connection), the mouse device tree shows up like this:

[image: Device Manager]

Disabling the "HID-compliant device" (highlighted above) solves the problem.  Users no longer experience delay at login.  I haven't found any negative effects (though maybe it is no longer possible to control the mouse color; I didn't reinstall the Microsoft Keyboard & Mouse Center software to check).

Windows tells me that I have to reboot in order to disable the device after selecting the option.  However, just disconnecting and reconnecting the mouse also works.

Comment: This appears to also happen with a Razer Mouse. I found the same issue independently in a trace shared by a coworker. I found that FindLampArray spins in a Sleep(250) loop and that (indirectly) causes explorer.exe to hang for 308 seconds.
https://twitter.com/BruceDawson0xB/status/1392178341826813953

Comment: Hit the same issue recently: https://twitter.com/KirillOsenkov/status/1376001098217971712

There's an internal Microsoft bug on this and they are investigating.

Comment: I have this problem with a Razor mouse too.

Comment: @KirillOsenkov Thanks for following up with the appropriate people at MS.  I filed a report through Feedback Hub but it does not seem to have been noticed.  I feel like that's the case with anything that I send in through there, I have a couple of other long-lasting reproducible-but-obscure Windows 10 bugs that have never been addressed...  :-\